# the php is working fine when i click to register it don't show already exist but open the next activity which is login

Tags: php, android, android-json

JsonResponse in PHP not responding to my android app.. i want to validate if user already exist. the php is working fine when i click to register it don't show already exist but open the next activity which is login

```
bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String name = etName.getText().toString();
            final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            Integer age =null;
            if(!etAge.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))

            {
                age=Integer.parseInt(etAge.getText().toString());

            }
            final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

            //test of error

            if (name.equals("") || username.equals("") || age == null || 
password.equals(""))  {
                builder.setTitle("Something Went Wrong");
                builder.setMessage("Please fill in all the 
fileds").setPositiveButton("OK", null).create().show();

            }
            if(name.length()==0){
                etName.requestFocus();
                etName.setError("FIELD CANNOT BE EMPTY");
            }
            if(username.length()<=3){
                etUsername.requestFocus();
                etUsername.setError("4 CHARACTERS REQUIRED");
            }
            else if(!username.matches("[0-1a-zA-Z]+"))
            {
                etUsername.requestFocus();
                etUsername.setError("ENTER ONLY ALPHANUMIRIC CHARACTER");
            }
            else if(password.length()==0)
            {
                etPassword.requestFocus();
                etPassword.setError("FIELD CANNOT BE EMPTY");
            }
            if(password.length()<=3) {
                etUsername.requestFocus();
                etUsername.setError("4 CHARACTERS REQUIRED");
            }
            else {

                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new 
Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new 
JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = 
jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                            if (success) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(register.this, 
login.class);
                                register.this.startActivity(intent);
                            } else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new 
AlertDialog.Builder(register.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        finish();
                    }
                };

                RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name, 
username, age, password, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(register.this);
                queue.add(registerRequest);
            }
        }
    });

    butback = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butback);

    butback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(register.this, login.class);
            register.this.startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

}

```
<html>
<head>
<title>insert incident</title></head>
<body>
<h1>incident report</h1>
<form action ="<?PHP $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="post">
Name <input type="text" name="name" value=""/><br/>
age <input type="text" name="age" value=""/><br/>
username <input type="text" name="username" value=""/><br/>
password <input type="password" name="password" value=""/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Login">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: put your json response

Answer (score 0):

here is my php code

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "incidb");

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $age = $_POST["age"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];


    if($name == '' || $age == '' || $username == '' || $password == ''){
        echo 'please fill all values';
    }else{
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM newuser WHERE username='$username' ";

        $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql));

        if(isset($check)){
                $response = array();
                $response["Username already exist"] = true; 
        }else{              
            $sql = "INSERT INTO newuser (name,age,username,password) 
VALUES('$name','$age','$username','$password')";
            if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
                $response = array();
                $response["success"] = true;  
            }else{
                $response = array();
                $response["oops! Please try again!"] = false; 
            }
        }
        mysqli_close($con);

        print_r(json_encode($response));
}

?>
```